# A faster way to compute largest prime factor (Again, but a lot better)

Tags: javascript, beginner, programming-challenge, primes, factors

I came up with this code after implementing the feedback given by [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success). The previous one ([A faster way to compute the largest prime factor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219063/a-faster-way-to-compute-the-largest-prime-factor)) tested my patience, but still failed to give the answer on time. This one is an improvement as it gives the answer without much delay.

**The question** (Euler project problem #3)

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

**Logic:**

Keep dividing the number `n` by all the factors, starting from the smallest one. The value of `n` left in the end will be the largest prime factor of the original value of `n`.

**My code:**

```js
function problem3(n){
    for(let i=2; i<n; i++){
        if(n%i === 0)n = n/i;
        }
    return n;
}
console.log(problem3(600851475143));
```

**Improvement:**

- No need to loop through all the numbers below `n`
- Remove the nested `for` loops, replacing them by only one
- No need to check if a number is prime or not

**My question:** Even though it is a lot better*, but still, how can it be improved further?

<sub>* Really, it's a lot than the previous one as it used to be so slow that I never saw the output for 600851475143</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's buggy. Consider input `8`.

---

Also, consider an input which is a very large prime. E.g. `2147483647`. Your current code would take about 2147483645 trial divisions. It's possible to do it with only 46340 trial divisions while keeping the code very simple. Can you see how?

> Hint: 46340 is the square root, rounded down.

And that's easily optimised to 23171. Can you see how?

> Hint: only one prime is even.